# How do you an echo out an array in Wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress, echo

I have the following code which extracts the first thirty words from the post content:

```
$extract = explode (' ', $post->post_content);
$first_thirty = array_slice($extract, 0, 30);
echo  $first_thirty;
```

But when I `echo $first_thirty;` it prints "array", how can I get it print properly.

Comment: `print_r($first_thirty);` `var_dump($first_thirty);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the first thirty words back into a string, then echo it:

```
echo implode(' ', $first_thirty);
```